# Strapi responds with 401 after some time of inactivity, works after reload

Tags: postgresql, nuxt.js, strapi, http-status-code-401, nuxtjs3

After some time of inactivity, api calls return a 401, when reloading (once or twice) it works.

I call the api using `useStrapi4()` and `find()`. The `Public` role has permission to `find` and `findOne` of the collection type I am querying.

The request:

```js
...
mounted() {
  this.$strapi.find("home").then(({data}) => {
    this.page = data;
  });
},
...
```

The response:

```json
{
  "data": null,
  "error": {
    "status": 401,
    "name": "UnauthorizedError",
    "message": "Missing or invalid credentials",
    "details": {}
  }
}
```

I have a hunch that it may have something to do the the JWT token, but I don't know how to debug it.

- Strapi 4.1.9
- Nuxt 3.0.0-rc.5
- DB PostgreSQL
- Hosted on Railway.app

Comment: were you able to find the solution for the same? I'm too facing the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Strapi kills the server when there are fewer than two connections for some time. So setting `pool` to `0` makes sure that the server is up even if there are zero connections.

This worked for me:

```
// config/database.js

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  connection: {
    // other config …
    pool: {
      min: 0, // ← this line is important
    }
  },
});
```